# Can't convert Panda series to DateTime

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, format

I'm trying to convert my a panda series to a Datetime format but I'm getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

My current code is:

```
  import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as dates

    file = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/saif/Dropbox/Personal Health/Mega Sleep Data/Merged Database.xlsx')
    Sleep= file.parse('Sheet 1')  


Sleep.rename(columns={'levels/summary/deep/minutes': 'TotalDeepSleep', 'levels/summary/deep/thirtyDayAvgMinutes': 'AverageDeepSleep'}, inplace=True)

    ### converting dates to DateTime

    **Ω**
```

The dates are current stored as:

```
print(Sleep['dateOfSleep'].head())
0    2018-07-02
1    2018-07-03
2    2018-07-04
3    2018-07-05
4    2018-07-07
Name: dateOfSleep, dtype: object
```

Comment: How are you attempting to convert to datetime? You should be able to do `Sleep['dateOfSleep'] = pd.to_datetime(Sleep['dateOfSleep'])`

Comment: You're right! I thought that the DataFrame had to be inserted in place of pd!